# Apache poi multiline bullet point is working but not multiple paragaraph?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Generate word document using apache poi library bullet point is working but i trying multiple paragraph not working,i have pasted below,

my java class code :

```
package samplebuller;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.TextAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFAbstractNum;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFNumbering;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;



public class Samplebullet {
       String fileName=""; 
       InputStream in = null;
       CTAbstractNum abstractNum = null;
       public Samplebullet() {
           try {
               InputStream in = new FileInputStream("numbering.xml");
               abstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.parse(in);
           } catch (XmlException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
       public String createDocument(String fileName, String content) {
           this.fileName=fileName;
           XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

           doc.createNumbering();
           XWPFNumbering numbering=null;
           numbering=doc.createNumbering();
               XWPFParagraph para = doc.createParagraph();
               para.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
               para.setNumID(addListStyle(abstractNum, doc, numbering));
               XWPFRun run=para.createRun();
               run.setText("JAVA Code");
               run.addBreak();
               XWPFParagraph para1 = doc.createParagraph();
               para1.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
               para1.setNumID(addListStyle(abstractNum, doc, numbering));
               XWPFRun run1=para.createRun();
               run1.setText("PYTHON CODE");
               run1.addBreak();

               XWPFParagraph para2 = doc.createParagraph();
               para2.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
               para2.setNumID(addListStyle(abstractNum, doc, numbering));
               XWPFRun run2=para.createRun();
               run2.setText("PHP CODE");
               run2.addBreak();


           try {
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
               doc.write(out);
               out.close();
               in.close();
           } catch(Exception e) {}
           return null;
       }
       private BigInteger addListStyle(CTAbstractNum abstractNum, XWPFDocument doc, XWPFNumbering numbering) {
           try {

               XWPFAbstractNum abs = new XWPFAbstractNum(abstractNum, numbering);
               BigInteger id = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
               boolean found = false;
               while (!found) {
                   Object o = numbering.getAbstractNum(id);
                   found = (o == null);
                   if (!found)
                       id = id.add(BigInteger.ONE);
               }
               abs.getAbstractNum().setAbstractNumId(id);
               id = numbering.addAbstractNum(abs);
               return doc.getNumbering().addNum(id);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               return null;
           }
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           String fileName="Test.docx";
           new Samplebullet().createDocument(fileName, "First Level@@Second Level@@Second Level@@First Level");
       }
}
```

My xml numbering file code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <w:numbering xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mac/office/2008/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:mv="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mac:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">

    <w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="0">
    <w:nsid w:val="3A6A237F"/>
    <w:multiLevelType w:val="hybridMultilevel"/>
    <w:tmpl w:val="5C9890C4"/>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="0" w:tplc="0409000F"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%1."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="1" w:tplc="04090019" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerLetter"/><w:lvlText w:val="%2."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="1440" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="2" w:tplc="0409001B" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerRoman"/><w:lvlText w:val="%3."/><w:lvlJc w:val="right"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="2160" w:hanging="180"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="3" w:tplc="0409000F" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%4."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="2880" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="4" w:tplc="04090019" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerLetter"/><w:lvlText w:val="%5."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="3600" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="5" w:tplc="0409001B" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerRoman"/><w:lvlText w:val="%6."/><w:lvlJc w:val="right"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="4320" w:hanging="180"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="6" w:tplc="0409000F" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%7."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="5040" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="7" w:tplc="04090019" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerLetter"/><w:lvlText w:val="%8."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="5760" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="8" w:tplc="0409001B" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerRoman"/><w:lvlText w:val="%9."/><w:lvlJc w:val="right"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="6480" w:hanging="180"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    </w:abstractNum>

    <w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="1">
    <w:nsid w:val="5E7736F6"/>
    <w:multiLevelType w:val="hybridMultilevel"/>
    <w:tmpl w:val="F602653C"/>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="0" w:tplc="0409000F"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%1."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="720" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="1" w:tplc="04090001"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/><w:lvlText w:val=""/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="1440" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Symbol" w:hAnsi="Symbol" w:hint="default"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="2" w:tplc="04090003"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="bullet"/><w:lvlText w:val="o"/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="2340" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii="Courier New" w:hAnsi="Courier New" w:hint="default"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="3" w:tplc="0409000F" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%4."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="2880" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="4" w:tplc="04090019" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerLetter"/><w:lvlText w:val="%5."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="3600" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="5" w:tplc="0409001B" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerRoman"/><w:lvlText w:val="%6."/><w:lvlJc w:val="right"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="4320" w:hanging="180"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="6" w:tplc="0409000F" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/><w:lvlText w:val="%7."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="5040" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="7" w:tplc="04090019" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerLetter"/><w:lvlText w:val="%8."/><w:lvlJc w:val="left"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="5760" w:hanging="360"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    <w:lvl w:ilvl="8" w:tplc="0409001B" w:tentative="1"><w:start w:val="1"/><w:numFmt w:val="lowerRoman"/><w:lvlText w:val="%9."/><w:lvlJc w:val="right"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left="6480" w:hanging="180"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>
    </w:abstractNum>

    <w:num w:numId="1"><w:abstractNumId w:val="1"/></w:num>
    <w:num w:numId="2"><w:abstractNumId w:val="0"/></w:num>

    </w:numbering>
```

Please anyone help me multiline bullet point,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There mainly two issues with your code:

1. Your `run`s are all in `para`, which is the first paragraph. I don't believe that this shall be so.
2. Your `addListStyle` creates abstract numberings each time it is called. So your `numbering.xml` gets unnecessary big and contains multiple abstract numberings with the same IDs 0 and 1. The `addListStyle` should be called only once. The `BigInteger` should be used as `numID` for all paragraphs which uses the same numbering.

But I would the whole thing not do that complicated. Consider the following example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTNumbering;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordBulletOrDecimalList {

 static String cTAbstractNumBulletXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\uF0B7\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Symbol\" w:hAnsi=\"Symbol\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u2013\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:cs=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"bullet\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"\u26Ac\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Courier New\" w:hAnsi=\"Courier New\" w:hint=\"default\"/></w:rPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";

 static String cTAbstractNumDecimalXML = 
  "<w:abstractNum xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" w:abstractNumId=\"0\">"
+ "<w:multiLevelType w:val=\"hybridMultilevel\"/>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"0\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"720\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"1\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"1440\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "<w:lvl w:ilvl=\"2\" w:tentative=\"1\"><w:start w:val=\"1\"/><w:numFmt w:val=\"decimal\"/><w:lvlText w:val=\"%1.%2.%3\"/><w:lvlJc w:val=\"left\"/><w:pPr><w:ind w:left=\"2160\" w:hanging=\"360\"/></w:pPr></w:lvl>"
+ "</w:abstractNum>";

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The List:");

  CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(cTAbstractNumBulletXML);
  //CTNumbering cTNumbering = CTNumbering.Factory.parse(cTAbstractNumDecimalXML);

  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = cTNumbering.getAbstractNumArray(0);

  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);

  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

  BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);

  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numID);
   run = paragraph.createRun();
   run.setText("List item " + i); 
   if (i < 2) paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0);
   if (i == 1) {
    paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    paragraph.setNumID(numID);
    paragraph.getCTP().getPPr().getNumPr().addNewIlvl().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Sub list item " + i + " a");
    paragraph.setSpacingAfter(0); 
   }
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Paragraph after the list.");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordBulletOrDecimalList.docx");    
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

  System.out.println("CreateWordBulletOrDecimalList written successully");
 }
}
```